# Rege: find all individual words between double curly braces

Tags: javascript, regex

My regex is pretty weak so I need some help. I have a case where I need to find all individual words between curly braces. I need a single regex to do the below use case. I cant post process the regex.

For example

```
Hi {{username}}, You total is {{ user.total - discount}}, please pay by date {{moment.utc(userPaymentDateTime)}}
```

The output here should be like

```
[username, user.total, - , discount, moment.utc,userPaymentDateTime]
```

---

---

I've Tried the following

```
\{{(.*?)\}}

Output is [username,user.total-discount,moment.utc(userPaymentDateTime)]
```

---

```
(?!{{)\s*(\w+)\s*(?=}})

Output is [username, discount]
```

Comment: Kindly do add your efforts in form of regex/code in your question, which is highly encouraged on SO(not my downvote btw), thank you.

Comment: What is your attempt? Please read [ask] and provide a [example]. This should (a) show the __regex__ you tried, (b) the __Javascript code__ you tested, and (c) the output you got, even not expected. Please [edit] your question and add required information there!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the ECMAScript 2018+ compliant JavaScript environment, you can use

```js
(?<=\{\{(?:(?!\{\{|}}).)*)[^\s()]+(?=(?:(?!\{\{|}}).)*}})
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tVkOyd/1/). *Details*:

- `(?<=\{\{(?:(?!\{\{|}}).)*)` - a positive lookbehind that requires the following sequence of patterns to occur immediately to the left of the current location:

  - `\{\{` - a `{{` string
  - `(?:(?!\{\{|}}).)*` - any char other than line break chars, zero or more times, that does not start a `}}` or `{{` char sequences
- `[^\s()]+` - one or more chars other than whitespace, `(` and `)`
- `(?=(?:(?!\{\{|}}).)*}})` - a positive lookahead that requires the following sequence of patterns to occur immediately to the right of the current location:

  - `(?:(?!\{\{|}}).)*` - any char other than line break chars, zero or more times, that does not start a `}}` or `{{` char sequences
  - `}}` - a `}}` string.

Comment: Though this solution worked out perfectly, the case where I was trying to fix this didn't. None the less, thanks for the perfect solution